# jar edit and re-compile in simple way

Tags: java

I have a jar file called ScreenCapture.jar

I use http://jd.benow.ca/ what is in there. I have even downloaded jd-gui

This is what it shows me

[image: screenCapture]

I can see the ScreenCapture.class file. I want to edit 2 lines here

```
      Thread.sleep(15000L);
      to
      Thread.sleep(60000L);
```

and

```
driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1024, 768));
to
driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1200, 800));
```

But this file is not editable.

My question is, how to edit it? like how to decompile it so I can edit it and then recompile it. So I can just re-upload my jar file and everything gets back to normal?

Btw, I know nothing about java, and I don't have any special application/software installed on my machine

Comment: You should find some tool for reverse enginering. New Intellij idea got it. jar, war is just compresed folder like zip.

Answer (score 10):

follow these steps:

1. Create an eclipse project
2. add the jar as a dependency to that project
3. Create a new class named ScreenCapture.java in the package screencapture.
4. copy the whole source from your JD too view the screenshot of which u attached here.
5. change the code which u want.
6. build the project
7. check the bin folder of you eclipse project . this will have the new compiled .class file.
8. open the jar in winrar and copy the .class file from bin folder into your jar.
9. and you are done.

Comment: can you explain how you can add the jar as a dependency to that project

Answer (score 1):

Save the source files by clicking save menu item under file. It will generate src.ip file.Then you can do whatever you want.

Comment: ohkaky, it's saved.. I did the changes, now how can I re-jar it? How to re-compile it now?

Comment: You can use ides either eclipse or netbeans. Or you  can do it using jar command. Go through link https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html

Answer (score 0):

On your first question 
JD-GUI is just a viewer you need to use dex2jar to retrieve the JAR file; decompile and save the classes you need to change; import JAR and JAVA files in your Android Studio; modify; recompile and repackaged.

Comment: Attaching external links is good but posting excerpts (what you've found useful related to this question) from them would be much helpful.