# Compile a folder with java classes into a JAR

Tags: jar, decompiling, recompile

I had a jar file paymentService.jar which had a lot of class files. I have decompiled a class file, made some changes to it's code and created a .java file. I have kept the .java file in the same location as .class file.

How can I recompile the .java file and then recreate a JAR of the folder.

I can't compile the .java file using **javac /my/../example.java** because imports will fail.

Comment: Can it be a dupe of: https://stackoverflow.com/q/27329537/4636715 I am not sure as I could not quite exactly get your objective.

Comment: Goal is to edit a class file inside a JAR